# Changes inside of events of change in route don't trigger change detection in Angular

Tags: angular

I'm trying to listen `popstate` events in navigation. I have some data in `LocalStorage`, and i want to set or not (based on this event `popstate`) this value to a component variable, and show it in template. But, apparently, change detection of Angular is not working. I believe that because `console.log` is being showed (inside listener), but value is not being update.

Below is the simplified code that reproduces the problem:

---

app.component.html

```html
<router-outlet></router-outlet>

<a routerLink="route-1">route 1</a>
<br>
<a routerLink="route-2">route 2</a>
```

---

route1.component.html

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-route1',
  template: ` <p>route1 works!</p> <p>{{variable}}</p> `,
  styles: [],
})
export class Route1Component implements OnInit {

  variable: string = 'one';

  ngOnInit(): void {
    fromEvent(window, 'popstate').subscribe(() => {
      console.log('window popstate event');
      this.variable = 'two';
    });
  }
}
```

---

route2.component.html

```js
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-route2',
  template: `
    <p>route2 works!</p>
    <p>{{ variable }}</p>
  `,
  styles: [],
})
export class Route2Component implements OnInit {
  variable: string = 'one';

  constructor(private router: Router, private location: Location) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.location.subscribe((test) => {
      console.log('popevent route 2: ', test);
      this.variable = 'two';
    });
  }
}
```

---

I've tried two ways of listen to `popstate` events, both has the same problem.

If a go to `route-1`, then to `route-2`, then press Back from browser, i would expect that template is showing "route1 works! two", but it's showing "route1 works! one". Detail, Logging is showing "window popstate event". Same thing if i go to `route-2`, then `route-1`, and Back to `route-1`.

Can anyone help me with this?

---

**EDIT 1** I already tested with `ChangeDetectorRef` after variable change. It isn't working to

Comment: You should try adding the listener on the app component, not on the route.

Comment: @alphapilgrim, indeed, it works. But how to handle with individual behaviour by component?

Comment: You could register this handler but it wouldnt work as soon as you nav'd away.